# Good orm for osgi

Tags: java, database, orm, osgi

I'm looking for java orm with good osgi support. I've read hibernate but some problems occurs when it comes to class loading.

Comment: Hibernate is not OSGi friendly, or even OSGi bundles for that matter.  You can get the SpringSource bundled versions but they can still cause issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [Eclipse Link](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink). I have not tried it with OSGi, but they have instructions how to install it under OSGi environment ([here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Installing_and_Configuring_EclipseLink#Installing_EclipseLink_OSGi)), so I assume it should work.

Answer (score 5):

Use [Aries JPA](http://aries.apache.org/modules/jpaproject.html), it works will all/most JPA providers, for a tutorial see [here](http://jaxenter.com/tutorial-using-jpa-in-an-osgi-environment-36661.html)

EclipseLink works nicely in OSGi and is well documented, but the Aries JPA project allows you to be vendor independent and switch them out easily.

If you're using Karaf there are already features for Aries transaction and JPA.

Comment: I've used EclipseLink in conjunction with Aries and had great success. JPA in general can be a little tricky in OSGi but there are good articles on dealing with it.

Answer (score 0):

I have used [myBatis](http://www.mybatis.org/) and it works well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm probably a lone voice in this, but I'm using Hibernate very successfully with Karaf and a number of different databases.  Now, I'm not saying it was easy, but I was able to document the steps I had to take to use Hibernate in Karaf on my [blog](http://os-tech.blogspot.com/) If you decide to use Hibernate and run into any issues, let me know and I'll be happy to help.